# How to optimize this MySQL query? (moving window)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, window, query-optimization

I have a huge table (400k+ rows), where each row describes an event in the FX market. The table's primary key is an integer named 'pTime' - it is the time at which the event occurred in [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time.

My database is queried repeatedly by my computer during a simulation that I constantly run. During this simulation, I pass an input pTime (I call it qTime) to a MySQL procedure. qTime is a query point from that same huge table. Using qTime, my procedure filters the table according to the following rule:

Select only those rows whose pTime is a maximum 2 hours away from the input qTime on any day.

ex.

```
query point: `2001-01-01  07:00`
                                 lower limit: `ANY-ANY-ANY 05:00`
                                 upper limit: `ANY-ANY-ANY 09:00`
```

After this query the query point will shift by 1 row (5 minutes), and a new query will be initiated:

```
query point: `2001-01-01  07:05`
                                 lower limit: `ANY-ANY-ANY 05:05`
                                 upper limit: `ANY-ANY-ANY 09:05`
```

This is the way I accomplish that:

```
SELECT * FROM mergetbl WHERE
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(pTime,"%H:%i"),FROM_UNIXTIME(qTime,"%H:%i")))/3600
BETWEEN -2 AND 2
```

Although I have an index on pTime, this piece of code significantly slows down my software.

I would like to pre-process this statement for each value of pTime (which will later serve as an input qTime), but I cannot figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rely **only** on time - I'd suggest you to add another column of [time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html) type with time fraction of `pTime` and perform queries over it

Answer (score 2):

You query still needs to scan every value because of how you are testing the time within certain ranges that are not spanning of the index.

You would need to separate your time into a different field and index to gain the benefit of an index here.

(note: answer was edited to fix my original misunderstanding of the question)

Comment: Calculate that in code outside of the query; whatever dates he wants. Just don't calculate it for every single row, inline with the WHERE clause.

Comment: "from the input qTime on **any day**". How do you propose to compose `BETWEEN` condition for **any day**? OP doesn't have 2 timestamps which the row should be within, but he has 2 times, that every suitable row should be within for literally any day.

Comment: I see what you mean. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

DATETIME is the wrong type in this case because no system of DATETIME storage I know of will be able to use an index if you're examining *only* the TIME part of the value.  The easy optimization is, as others have said, to store the time separately in a field of datatype TIME (or perhaps some kind of integer offset) and index *that*.

If you really want the two pieces of information in the same column you'll have to roll your own data format, giving primacy to the time type.  You could use a string type in the format HH:MM:SS YYYY-MM-DD or you could use a NUMERIC field in which the whole number part is a seconds-from-midnight offset and the decimal part a days-from-reference-date offset.

Also, consider how much value the index will be.  If your range is four hours, assuming equal distribution during the day, this index will return 17% of your database.  While that will produce some benefit, if you're doing any other filtering I would try to work that into your index as well.